# Find the number of homes with 3000 sq ft , 3 number of bedrooms and 40 years of age?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

there is a dataset like this

```
area   bedroom  age  price

2600        3    20  550000
3000        4    15  565000
...
```

Now the questions are

1. find the price of the house with 2500 sft and 4 bedrooms and 5 years old?
2. find the home with 3000sft and 3 bedrooms and 40 years old?

I know 1st question can be done with Linear Regression. How should I do second question ?

Comment: If you want to find in your data set, you only have to apply a filter. Machine learning is useful to make future predictions, but, if you want to just find, ML is not need. Can you confirm if you are finding in your data set or predicting?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat Thanks for the reply....yeah even I was thinking that.... but the question is writtenn like that only.... I understood that if I have to find it in my dataset then I can use pandas operations....but if i have to predict then what do i need to do ?

Comment: And even if you feel that its not a prediction then please write it as answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1):

If it's "find *the* house" then that implies that you need to find the house with those specific attributes in the dataset. I'm not sure what programming language you're using but it should be pretty simple to do such a thing anyways.
If it's "find the price *of* a house with..." that implies there probably isn't such a house in the dataset and you need to train a predictive model to predict the price of such a house. You said to use linear regression, which is a fine choice, *if your data is linear*... But I would instead suggest an SVR (Support Vector Machine Regressor), and fine-tune some things like the kernel and regularization.